# Mapping array of strings to map

Tags: java, string, object, dictionary, mapping

I have an array of strings. How would you convert it into Map(String, Object). I need to convert it to a data object.

Comment: What do you want to map each String value _to_?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what kind of mapping you are trying to do?Maybe give some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `Map` is equivalent to an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). If we applied your case to this, you would end up with each `String` pointing to another `Object`.

If this is what you want, this would work:

```
String[] strs = new String[]; //Your string array, initialized elsewhere
Object[] os = new Object[];   //The objects that you want mapped.
Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // I use HashMap because it is the most generic

for(int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  m.put(strs[i], os[i]); //Add each object, os[i], to the map at position str[i]
}
```

If you just want the `String[]` to become a resizable array, you can use this:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList(strs);
```